# Functional equation $f(x+b) = f(x)+b$ where $b$ is any real number.

Tags: linear-transformations, functional-equations

So, I was asking myself about what functions have the property that if they are translated in the $x$ direction the result is the same as if it was translated in the $y$ direction.

So the question can be rephrased as what are all the functions $f$ that satisfy

$$f(x+b) = f(x)+b$$

for a $b$ parameter that is real.

I know that any straight line at $45^\circ$ will obey this property, since:

$$f(x)=x+c\Longrightarrow f(x+b) =x+b+c = x+c+b = f(x)+b$$

, but what are the other functions that obey it (if there are any)?

Comment: Put $x=0$, what do you obtain?

Comment: @lulu: no, we'd have $f(0+b)=f(0)+b$, which is completely different.

Comment: @TonyK  Oh, $b$ is meant to be fixed here?  I was just looking at the functional equation. My error.   I'll delete my earlier comment.  Note:  the phrase "where $b$ is any real number" is at least a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Given that $b$ is fixed, we can take any function we want on the interval $[0,b)$ and define it on all of $\mathbb R$ by translation.

Comment: Any function $f(x)$ where $g(x)=f(x)-x$ is constant or periodic with period dividing $b$ (in the other direction, take any function $g(x)$ with $g(x+b)=g(x)$ and let $f(x)=g(x)+x$).  Your $45^\circ$ lines are just the cases with $g(x)$ constant.  Note that $f(x)$ is continuous/differentiable/etc. iff $g(x)$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g:[0,1)\to\Bbb R$ be any function whatsoever. Then the function
$$f(x)=g\left(\left\{\frac{x}{b}\right\}\right)+b\left\lfloor\frac{x}{b}\right\rfloor$$
satisfies your equation (where we are taking the fractional and integral parts of $\dfrac{x}{b}$).

This is because $\left\{\dfrac{x+b}{b}\right\}$ is the same as $\left\{\dfrac{x}{b}\right\}$, and $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x+b}{b}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{b}\right\rfloor+1$. Essentially we are stretching the graph of $g$ by a factor of $b$ in the $x-$ and $y-$ directions, and duplicating it out to plus and minus infinity along a $45^\circ$ axis.